# multiple key in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am doing a simple cashier program using Python.

I got a dictionary that stores all the products in a Computer store.

```
products = [
    {"category": "laptops", "name":"APPLE MACBOOK AIR","price":1345,"offer":"yes"},
    {"category": "laptops", "name":"ASUS S533EQ 15.6","price":1448,"offer":"no"},
    {"category": "laptops", "name":"LENOVO IP 3","price":1308,"offer":"no"},
    {"category": "tablets", "name":"SAMSUNG 64GB GALAXY TAB","price":372,"offer":"no"},
    {"category": "tablets", "name":"APPLE 10.2-INCH IPAD","price":456,"offer":"yes"},
    {"category": "tablets", "name":"HUAWEI HW-BAH3 LTE","price":372,"offer":"yes"},
    {"category": "gameconsoles", "name":"NINTENDO SWITCH CONSOLE","price":457,"offer":"yes"},
    {"category": "gameconsoles", "name":"SONY PLAYSTATION 5","price":560,"offer":"no"},
    {"category": "gameconsoles", "name":"MICROSOFT XBOX CONSOLE","price":653,"offer":"yes"},
]
```

In my main menu, I have the following options:

1. List product by category
2. List product by alphabetically
3. List product by ascending price

This is my sample code to sort them

```
def list_prod_category():
    for x in sorted(products, key=itemgetter('category')):
        print(x)
```

However, I want to format my items neatly for user to "Add to cart" instead of seeing JSON format.

E.g.

1. APPLE MACBOOK AIR ($1345)
2. ASUS 15.6 ($1448)

How do I format it, in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified a bit of your code to format names in the mentioned way.

> Added a parameter to your function - which can take the value of any key in dictionary, `name`, `category`, `price` etc.
>
> And let this function do the job for all your needs.

Have a look into the below statements executed on IPython terminal.

```
In [18]: def list_prod_category(sort_by="category"): 
    ...:     for index, product in enumerate(sorted(products, key=itemgetter(sort_by))): 
    ...:         print(f"{index + 1}. {product['name']} (${product['price']})") 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                              

In [19]: list_prod_category("price") # Sort by price                                                                                                                              
1. SAMSUNG 64GB GALAXY TAB ($372)
2. HUAWEI HW-BAH3 LTE ($372)
3. APPLE 10.2-INCH IPAD ($456)
4. NINTENDO SWITCH CONSOLE ($457)
5. SONY PLAYSTATION 5 ($560)
6. MICROSOFT XBOX CONSOLE ($653)
7. LENOVO IP 3 ($1308)
8. APPLE MACBOOK AIR ($1345)
9. ASUS S533EQ 15.6 ($1448)

In [20]: list_prod_category("name") # Sory by name (Alphabetically)                                                                                                               
1. APPLE 10.2-INCH IPAD ($456)
2. APPLE MACBOOK AIR ($1345)
3. ASUS S533EQ 15.6 ($1448)
4. HUAWEI HW-BAH3 LTE ($372)
5. LENOVO IP 3 ($1308)
6. MICROSOFT XBOX CONSOLE ($653)
7. NINTENDO SWITCH CONSOLE ($457)
8. SAMSUNG 64GB GALAXY TAB ($372)
9. SONY PLAYSTATION 5 ($560)

In [21]: list_prod_category("category") # Sort by category                                                                                                                                         
1. NINTENDO SWITCH CONSOLE ($457)
2. SONY PLAYSTATION 5 ($560)
3. MICROSOFT XBOX CONSOLE ($653)
4. APPLE MACBOOK AIR ($1345)
5. ASUS S533EQ 15.6 ($1448)
6. LENOVO IP 3 ($1308)
7. SAMSUNG 64GB GALAXY TAB ($372)
8. APPLE 10.2-INCH IPAD ($456)
9. HUAWEI HW-BAH3 LTE ($372)

In [22]:
```

Thanks.

Comment: is it possible, based on the index of the product, i add the item into my basket[] ?

Comment: Yes, you can add it to the basket.

Comment: how should i add it into my array basket[]? so when users enter option 1:, i need to check what is option 1? because it  can be sorted differently, and i cant hard code the options

Comment: i could not figure out my if else for it. So if userInput == ? because the list could be many and its populate by a for loop.

Comment: Hmm, in the list; each item will have its own index, 0, 1, 2, 3...so on. So you can write a separate function `add_to_cart(index, basket=[])` something like this and put the selected items inside this. Ex: `basket.append(products[index])`, in this way based on your logic.